# How to make a text box wider for the big text fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i have table, i am using inline edit to edit the table, my issue was text box size is common
for all the td,
for example

if the td is small the text box looks like this

[image]

if the td is big the text box looks like this

[image]

can anyone help me how to make text box wider
for the big text fields and smaller
for small text field,
below is my code

```
< script >

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td.edit').click(function (e) {

        var $target = $(e.target);
        if ($target.is('#editbox')) {
            return;
        }
        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
        $(this).addClass('ajax');
        $(this).html('<input id="editbox"  size="10" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');

        $('#editbox').select();

    });

    $('td.edit').keydown(function (event) {
        arr = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
        if (event.which == 13) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "supplier/update.php",
                data: "value=" + $('.ajax input').val() + "&rowid=" + arr[2] + "&field=" + arr[1],
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                    $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('#editbox').live('blur', function () {
        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
    });
}); < /script>
```

Update:

Now it looks like

[image]

Comment: Have you tried CSS `#editbox { width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add style to your text box

```
this $(this).html('<input style="width:100%; box-sizing: border-box;" id="editbox"  size="10" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
```

or in **CSS**

```
input[type="text"] {
     width: 100%; 
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

for working this style in mozilla u should add `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: thanks its works by it now look like this its not fit inside the td please see the updated image

Comment: thank you chriz but unfortunately the still the same isuue its moveing little outside the td

Comment: @arok which browser u r using??  add this style too ` -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: its looks fine in google chrome ,but it issue in firefox

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with css:

```
input[type=text]{
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: i am using like this `$(this).html('<input id="editbox"  size="10" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');`

Comment: why use inline css... but if you want you could do it like this: `$(this).html('<input id="editbox" style="width:100%;" size="10" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');` or add it with jquery like: `$(this).html('<input id="editbox"  size="10" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">').find('input').css('width', '100%');`

Comment: its works by it now look like this its not fit inside the td please see the updated image

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the input has margin, border and padding if you remove all of those it doesnt break out but you also cant see the input unless you change its background-color. VisionN's box-sizing should(and actually will) solve your problem

```
input {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8nk3T/1/

or if you want to do it with js/jQuery

```
$(this).html('<input id="editbox" style="width:100%; -moz-box-sizing: 'border-box'; -webkit-box-sizing: 'border-box'; box-sizing: 'border-box';" size="10" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
```

or

```
$(this).html('<input id="editbox"  size="10" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">').find('input').css({
    'width': '100%',
    '-moz-box-sizing': 'border-box',
    '-webkit-box-sizing': 'border-box',
    'box-sizing': 'border-box'
});
```

EDIT: added vendor-prefixes